# Rav Moshe's pesak on milk

Tags: halacha, jewish-books

I want to learn his ruling and the logic behind it. Does anybody know where I can find it inside?

Comment: Have you searched for the question on Mi Yodeya? We definitely have had this asked in the past.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/130902/22152

Comment: Which ruling of his?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sources for Allowing Cholov Stam](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/130881/sources-for-allowing-cholov-stam)

Answer (score 3):

See [this](https://www.kashrut.com/articles/CholovStamHeter/) article discussing Rav Moshe's teshuvos about milk in America:

> In his famous teshuva about regular (not specially-supervised) milk –
> what we call “cholov stam”, Reb Moshe Feinstein zt“l rules that such
> milk is permissible, as governmental inspection of dairies serves as
> verification that milk from non-kosher animals is not present; since
> governmental inspection establishes the absence of milk from
> non-kosher animals as a known fact, the rule of Annan Sahadei – that
> we are all virtual witnesses to the fact – pertains, and it is as if
> there is actual visual supervision (by Klal Yisroel) of the milk in
> domestic dairies. ([Igros Moshe YD 1:47](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=917&st=&pgnum=80&hilite=))
>
> In [teshuva 49 (ibid.)](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=917&st=&pgnum=83&hilite=), Reb Moshe addresses the question of farms.
> Although there is governmental inspection of dairy plants, where milk
> is pasteurized and bottled, much of the milk comes from farms, which
> Reb Moshe describes as often lacking supervision. If so, how could the
> rule of Annan Sahadei apply to permit milk? Is there not a lapse in
> supervision, such that the milk was lacking any governmental
> supervision from the time it was farmed until it arrived at the dairy
> plant?
>
> Reb Moshe replied to the person who posed this question that Chazal
> were gozair on milk only at the point of its transfer to a Yisroel
> (“bo l’yad Yisroel”). Therefore, only milk which comes to the Jewish
> consumer from dairy processors can be prohibited as cholov akum; milk
> which is at farms and travels to dairy plants is not yet subject to
> the gezeirah. Once this milk is at the dairy plants, it is subject to
> governmental inspection and becomes the halachic equivalent of cholov
> Yisroel, as Annan Sahadei applies at that point and tells us to treat
> the milk as supervised by Yisroelim.

Comment: What's strange about this ruling is that the USDA doesn't test milk to determine if it is cow milk or not but is focused on bacterial  and other food borne contaminations

Comment: The actual ruling mentions that if they would mix in other ingredients without stating on the package they would be fined and possibly shut down. Not necessarily USDA inspections but overall ensuring the label is accurate, which they do as well